# How to use a file like a LIFO?

Tags: android, file, stack

My application sends a packet every 30 minutes. When the packet can't be sent, I want to store it (a simple string) inside a file called `error.log`. When the user presses a button called "restoreErrors", I want to extract a packet from `error.log` and try to resend it, according to the LIFO policy.

For example the file error.log is:

```
String1
String2
String3
```

And when the user presses the "restoreErrors" button, I need to load the saved packets in order:

```
while (!file.empty) {
  String str = loadUnsendedStringFromFile();
}
```

My problem is using the file like a LIFO, because I can read the String correctly, but I need to remove the currently extracted string (like POP in a stack model).

Thanks.

EDIT: Ok, I will use a simple list for achieve this, no need to store inside a file for every packet error... thanks

Comment: read into an array and send from N to 1. I don't see a real question unless you have billions of such strings, but question rules that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an [ArrayList](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html), you can call the add method to add unsent messages to your list. Then you can send them in the order you want (going up or down, with a simple for loop). Then, call the remove method to erase the sent string, it will leave you with the unsent Strings